# Android SQLiteDatabase syntax error

Tags: android, sqlite, syntax-error

I'm a newbie to Android. When I try to access the SQLiteDatabase locally, I'm in trouble with the syntax errors.
   The code that causes the syntax error is as follows.

```
final String tbl = "group";   
SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
db.delete(tbl, null, null);
```

There is a syntax error in `DELETE FROM group`. But it will be right when I alter the variable `tbl` to

```
final String tbl = "\"group\"";
```

Can anyone tell me the cause for the errors? Thanks.

Comment: What happens when you have some different name (other than **group**)? It seems to me that **group** is a reserved keyword that can not directly be used in the `FROM` clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"group" is part of 'GROUP BY' that is used for sorting the result in groups.

Comment: What do you mean "*sorting the result in groups*"?

Comment: Sorry Lion. Read this, then you'll understand: http://www.sql-tutorial.net/SQL-GROUP-BY.asp

Answer (score 0):

GROUP is a reserved word. If you put quotes around a qualifier (e.g. a tablename) you can use it even if it's a reserved word.

I would suggest to change the name.